# Matplotlib masking - Resetting the zorder of pixels depending on their current color value?

Tags: python, matplotlib, masking, clipping

1) I need a masking capability that does not seem to be present in Matplotlib.
(Please let me know if this is not the case).

2) Matplotlib has a Clipping capability, but the "clipped" out areas use the same zorder, 
therefore rendering several overlapping polygonal shapes which should be seen based on their zorder
fails in the areas where clipping was used to render one of them, because anything that we had previously render below the clipped areas is wiped out (all white so to speak).

3) If it were possible to "reset" the zorder of a given pixel color (our background color) at any time while rendering, then we would have resolved the issue with clipping. We would not even need clipping as we could just use a given zorder value for the parts that define our desired mask areas, and a lower zorder for the part to be clipped, and after rendering the part in question, we change the zorder of all the "white" pixels to a very low zorder value, and we have the masking capability working !

Here is a very simple example code to illustrate the need:

```
'''Example of two overlapping squares having arbitrary openings in them.
In this example the opening is just two smaller overlapping square, but it can be anything.
We want to paint the green and red squares so that we see what is behind the opening(s)'''
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

# This is to test if a well ordered polygon with slits (to define holes) can be rendered
quad_small = [(-0.2, -0.2), (-0.2, 0.2), (0.2, 0.2), (0.2, -0.2), (-0.2, -0.2)]
quad1x1 = [(-1, 1.), (-1, -1.), (1, -1.), (1., 1.), (-1, 1.)]

#Fill quad1x1 with green
x11 = [coord[0] for coord in quad1x1]
y11 = [coord[1] for coord in quad1x1]
plt.fill(x11, y11, facecolor='green', zorder=5)

'''Now make one or more holes, possibly overlapping holes, 
NOTE: if we use clipping to define the holes, Matplotlib sets the same zorder over all the clippped areas 
which was used. Also clipping does not work well with overlapping small squares. Would only work with nonoverlapping
squares.'''
xsq = [coord[0] for coord in quad_small]
ysq = [coord[1] for coord in quad_small]
plt.fill(xsq, ysq, facecolor='white', zorder=5)
xsq = [coord[0]+0.2 for coord in quad_small]
ysq = [coord[1]+0.2 for coord in quad_small]
plt.fill(xsq, ysq, facecolor='white', zorder=5)

'''At this point green and white openings have the same zorder=5.
We would need a call to change the zorder of all the 'white' pixels to a lower value, say 3'''

'''Now we want to render another polygon (red) with holes, but ONLY on areas not covered by the previous rendering,
we use a lower zorder so that we do not paint on the green part'''
x11 = [coord[0]+0.3 for coord in quad1x1]
y11 = [coord[1]+0.3 for coord in quad1x1]
plt.fill(x11, y11, facecolor='red', zorder=4)
xsq = [coord[0]+0.3 for coord in quad_small]
ysq = [coord[1]+0.3 for coord in quad_small]
plt.fill(xsq, ysq, facecolor='white', zorder=4)
xsq = [coord[0]+0.5 for coord in quad_small]
ysq = [coord[1]+0.5 for coord in quad_small]
plt.fill(xsq, ysq, facecolor='white', zorder=4)

'''The hole (white area) of the green square is not painted in red because the zorder of the white area is higher'''

plt.show()
```

[Snapshot of the rendering produced by the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSc9B.gif)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Would it be possible to use some code where you show what you want to achieve and that lets everyone see which problem you face?

Comment: Thanks for your interest / willingness to help: If we have a 10x10 square with multiple arbitrary holes, which can be overlapping. We can render the 10x10 square and then use zorder to make the arbitrary holes, but when doing so we need to use a higher zorder, and this wipes out anything that we had rendered before below the 10x10 square.

Comment: If you have a single image of shape 10 x 10, any region inside of it can either be shown or not shown. Zorder isn't relevant for that. So I fear I still do not understand the issue.

Comment: Sorry, a better example in chronological order: If we have a 10x10 square with multiple arbitrary holes, possibly overlapping holes. We can render the 
10x10 square and then use a higher zorder to make the arbitrary holes, or use the same zorder with Plotlib clipping. However, now we effectively have 
a zorder in  (white) areas (holes) that we need to overwrite with the next part rendered, but we can not use a higher zorder for the next part because 
by doing so we would be overwriting parts of the first 10x10 square with holes.

Comment: Why would holes have a zorder at all? They are just holes. I will reiterate that showing an example of the problem in terms of code will probably the only way to advance here.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of "masking" in a paint job ? In Matplotlib we use zorder as a mask, to prevent painting over areas that we do not want to paint. Whether we use a clipping (which actually paints the clipped areas with the same zorder), or a different zorder as the "mask", unless we can remove the mask after painting (reduce its value), we do not have a mask.

Comment: I have never used zorder to create a mask in matplotlib, so I'm unfamiliar with what you're talking about. Clipping is an option, but I do not understand what clipping has to do with zorder. For a last time I will state here that a [mcve] which shows the technique that does not work as desired would help you get an answer here.

Comment: I have updated my question with one example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems no clipping is even needed; because all surfaces are closed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))


xi, yi = np.array([(-0.2, -0.2), (-0.2, 0.2), (0.2, 0.2), (0.2, -0.2), (-0.2, -0.2)]).T
xo, yo = np.array([(-1, 1.), (-1, -1.), (1, -1.), (1., 1.), (-1, 1.)]).T

plt.fill(list(xo)+list(xi), list(yo)+list(yi), facecolor='green', zorder=5)
plt.fill(list(xo+.3)+list(xi+.3), list(yo+.3)+list(yi+.3), facecolor='red', zorder=4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You used a single square to define the opening !
Try with the hole defined with "overlapping quads" as I used in my original example,
and look at what happens in the area defined by the overlapping little quads.

Comment: Do you need help with defining the path of the two overlapping squares? If you want to do it automatically, you can also use `shapely` and calculate the [`.union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.union).

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed above does NOT work because it is for a single non-overlapping small quad. When we use two overlapping quads (slight modification to your example):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

xi, yi = np.array([(-0.2, -0.2), (-0.2, 0.2), (0.2, 0.2), (0.2, -0.2), (-0.2, -0.2)]).T
xo, yo = np.array([(-1, 1.), (-1, -1.), (1, -1.), (1., 1.), (-1, 1.)]).T

plt.fill(list(xo)+list(xi)+list(xi+0.1), list(yo)+list(yi)+list(yi+0.1), facecolor='green', zorder=5)
plt.fill(list(xo+.3)+list(xi+.3), list(yo+.3)+list(yi+.3), facecolor='red', zorder=4)

plt.show()
```

The results is as shown [in this snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkOnW.gif)

Also, even in your example with a single non-overlapping little square, if this square is not entirely "inside" the larger polygon, there is a rendering problem as shown below:

```
mport numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

xi, yi = np.array([(-0.2, -0.2), (-0.2, 0.2), (0.2, 0.2), (0.2, -0.2), (-0.2, -0.2)]).T
#xo, yo = np.array([(-1, 1.), (-1, -1.), (1, -1.), (1., 1.), (-1, 1.)]).T
xo, yo = np.array([(-.1, .1), (-1, -1.), (1, -1.), (1., 1.), (-.1, .1)]).T

#plt.fill(list(xo)+list(xi)+list(xi+0.1), list(yo)+list(yi)+list(yi+0.1), facecolor='green', zorder=5)
plt.fill(list(xo)+list(xi), list(yo)+list(yi), facecolor='green', zorder=5)
plt.fill(list(xo+.3)+list(xi+.3), list(yo+.3)+list(yi+.3), facecolor='red', zorder=4)

plt.show()
```

This is the result: [Bad rendering when little square is partially outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wukgj.gif)

Perhaps with Shapely union's you can get the first issue with overlapping little quads resolved, but how are we going to resolve the issue with the little quads partially outside ?
Please let me know what is best for this case.